# Show that $a_{n}\rightarrow b$ if and only if $\mid a_{n}- b\mid \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Show that $a_{n}\rightarrow b$ if and only if $\mid a_{n}- b\mid \rightarrow 0$.

I'm going with the textbook *Lectures on real analysis* written by Finnur Larusson. This question looks so trivial to me, so that I have no idea how to write the proper concise proof.

Here is my attempt

Forward: By definiton, $a_{n}\rightarrow b$ means b=$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_{n}$, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mid a_{n}-b\mid<\epsilon,\forall n\geq N$. Then $\mid a_{n}-b\mid \to0$

Backward: $\mid a_{n}-b\mid \to0$ means $0=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(a_{n}-b)$, then $0=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n}-b,$ therefore, $b=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$ and by definition, $a_{n}\to b$

I am not sure if my answer is a proper proof, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say that there is _really_ nothing to prove (when you expand out both definitions, you will end up with exactly the same). If the exercise is actually stated, is probably a bad joke from the author.

Comment: @Will M This problem has been given probably to help students structure their arguments and learn how to apply definitions, and understand if and only if statements.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $a_n \rightarrow b$, there exists $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|a_n-b|=|(a_n-b)-0|< \epsilon$. Hence the forward direction is proved. That is all you require. The backwards direction holds similarly.